# Is 'one in five (people/Americans)' etc. singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Suppose, we have a sentence

> Only one in five Americans under 30 approve(s) of Donald Trump.

Is 'one in five' and similar expressions grammatically plural or singular?

Comment: One is singular. Larger numbers are plural

Comment: Yes. It can be either singular or plural. This is really a matter of style as opposed to grammar, because it depends on if there are exactly five people—so this actually equates to a single person—of if there are thousands of people and *only one in five* still means many people. Different people will use a different form. There is no single correct answer here.